# Geometry nodes, disable object rotation

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms

is there a way to **ignore object rotation** using **geometry nodes** so Object rotation has no effect on our geoNode?

[image]

Comment: Other than the duplicate, there's also an older question with Robin Betts' answer for Blender 3.x, which is better than mine (just one "transform geometry" node): [Geometry Nodes: How to lock a geometry's global orientation using a Self Object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/280467/60486)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since The Chris' answer relies on experimental branch (Blender 4.1α), and the latest stable version, Blender 4.0.2 still has the *Rotation* socket blue, I decided to rework my comment into an answer.

This answer will probably get outdated soon, but since some people still use as old versions of Blender as 2.69, surely some geonoders will stay on 3.6 for a while…

### Blender 4.0 and newer

Chris' answer, but if your socket is blue, just convert it to purple and back:

[image]

Here's a more thorough answer, involving also canceling (inverting) scaling and translation:

[How do you invert a transformation in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/309021/60486)

### Blender 3.x

Robin Betts' answer is better:

[Geometry Nodes: How to lock a geometry's global orientation using a Self Object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/280487/60486)

Continue reading mine only as alternative explanation:

Multiply the XYZ rotations by $-1$, and apply them separately in reversed order:

[image]

You could maybe optimize it by recalculating a single XYZ Euler equivalent, but I haven't figured how or why exactly it doesn't work.

There's also a *Vector Rotate → Set Position* alternative, but according to my [tests](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/297620/60486), it takes 7 times more time than a single *Transform Geometry*, and since we only need 3 of these here… Yeah.

[image]

Comment: thank u, can u explain why we should apply transform geometry 3 times?

Comment: @Pooyaheydari *Transform Geometry* node applies the euler rotation in XYZ order. So by using it 3 times, we can force it to rotate first around Z, then around Y, and finally arounx X, which results in reversed ZYX order.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Just invert the rotation of the object itself.

[image]

Comment: Damn I can't access my PC rn, why your Object info rotation socket is purple? It's newest Blender or it happens when you connect it to purple socket? Normally I use euler to rotation node... also B3.6- you need to either use set position + vector rotate node (it has "invert" option) or split the axes (vector math multiply <-1, 0, 0> for example to get x axis, minus is there to invert) and use 3 separate "transform geo" nodes in order z y x

Comment: thank you, which blender version do you use?

Comment: it is version 4.1

Comment: I can see the version can be downloaded [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/), for some reason Blender Launcher fails to show it on a list...