Instances Random Rotation messes up Rotate Instances toward Object
I have this geo node, in which I can rotate instances toward object. What I want to do is add some randomization, rotation offset, or any fancy things before the Rotate Toward Object, but after all it must respect the final Rotate Toward Object as the main result, controlled by the Factor value. For example, if the Factor moving toward 1, then all other rotation modifications other than the Rotate Toward Object will have lesser effect.


But if I plug the random rotation in,I can see that the random rotation still takes effect, even though Rotate Toward Object now having Factor at 1. This suggests that the Instance Rotation I'm using for the calculation is not correct, how can I fix this behavior?



Have you tried the Rotate Rotation node?

Subtracting two rotation vectors does not make much sense unless both rotations are around the same axis X, Y or Z. The reason is that ONE rotation is in fact THREE rotations, by default in GN, first around X, then around Y, eventually around Z. Consequently, applying one full rotation after the other is very different from applying one rotation around X with the delta X angle, then around Y with the delta Y angle, and eventually around Z with the delta Z angle. You can have a look here e.g. about inverting a rotation: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/280487/177431
